# Matrix with characteristic equation equal to the rows of pascal triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, binomial-coefficients, characteristic-polynomial

Given the polynomial $P_n(x)$ corresponding to the $n$-th row of the Pascal triangle, find the matrix with characteristic equation $P_n(x)$.

Is there any way of doing this without using the binomial coefficient closed form solution? That is, just using the recurrence relation that defines the Pascal Triangle.

Comment: **Key concept**:  the Companion Matrix of the polynoimial

Comment: You write *the* matrix with characteristic polynomial $P_n(x)$, but of course there are many such matrices for each $n$.